# how to reset value of groups of a Test method in TestNG when running the programme

Tags: java, annotations, testng

With two groups defined already:

```
public class GroupA {

    @BeforeGroups(groups = "groupA")
    public void beforeGroup1(){
        System.out.println("In before GroupA");
    }
}

public class GroupB {

    @BeforeGroups(groups = "groupB")
    public void beforeGroup1(){
        System.out.println("In beforeGroupB");
    }
}
```

The test class is:

```
public class TestCls {

    @Test(groups="groupA")
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("In Test Class");
    }

}
```

in the code of BeforeSuite, trying to reset the value of groups to "groupB" using the following code, it doesn't work as expected.

```
public class Suite {

    @BeforeSuite()
    public void test() throws NotFoundException {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();      
        CtClass ct = pool.get(TestCls.class.getName());   

        //reset attribute groups from groupA to groupB 
        CtMethod ctMethod = ct.getDeclaredMethod("test");
        MethodInfo ctMethodInfo = ctMethod.getMethodInfo();
        ConstPool cp = ctMethodInfo.getConstPool(); 

        //reset attribute groups from groupA to groupB
        AnnotationsAttribute attribute = (AnnotationsAttribute)ctMethodInfo.getAttribute(AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
        Annotation annotation = attribute.getAnnotation("org.testng.annotations.Test"); 
        ArrayMemberValue arrayMemberValue = new ArrayMemberValue(cp);
        StringMemberValue[] memberValues = new StringMemberValue[]{new StringMemberValue("groupB", cp)};
        arrayMemberValue.setValue(memberValues);
        annotation.addMemberValue("groups", arrayMemberValue);  
        attribute.setAnnotation(annotation);  
        ctMethodInfo.addAttribute(attribute);

        //check if groups changed successfully
        Annotation annotation2 = attribute.getAnnotation("org.testng.annotations.Test"); 
        MemberValue[] text = ((ArrayMemberValue)annotation2.getMemberValue("groups")).getValue();  
        System.out.println("the groups after modified is " + text[0]); 
    }
}
```

the output is

```
the groups after modified is groupB
In beforeGroup1
In Test Class
```

Comment: the output is "the groups after modified is groupB;In before GroupA;In Test Class", doesn't run groupB

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify TestNG annotation values at runtime, you can use an [AnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers).

```
public class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
  public void transform(ITest annotation, Class<?> testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    annotation.setGroups(new String[]{"groupB"});
  }
}
```

Comment: how to involve this method after "BeforeSuite", especially how to get the annotation

Comment: Why do you want it after BeforeSuite? `ITest` is the internal representation of the Test annotation.